# jQuery Datatables failing search on a column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a site where I am using jQuery Datatables (http://datatables.net/)

Everything is working apart from the search on one of the columns. I haven't done anything specific to this column so it should just work shouldn't it?

Here is the javascript I am using

```
if(('.data-tables').length > 0) {
var source = $('.data-tables').attr('data-dtjson');

$('.data-tables').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": source,
    "aoColumns": [
      { "mData": "2" },
      { "mData": "6" },
      { "mData": "start_date_formatted" },
      { "mData": "actions" }
  ]
});
$.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
    "sSortAsc": "header headerSortDown",
    "sSortDesc": "header headerSortUp",
    "sSortable": "header"
});
}
```

The column is questions is mData: "6".

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this code was fine, it was something todo with the columns I was pulling out. It didn't seem to like me pulling out columns I wasn't using in the table.